# NumPy loadtxt hash strings in data columns

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to load data sets which looks like this:

```
MD1,MD2,MD3,MD4,MD5
8,5,6,4,5
5,##,2,8,9
4,9,8,2,4
#i,2,9,7,2
```

etc. 
This is a strongly reduced example and therefore I need a General solution.

The form of non values (like '##' and '#i') is depend on the measurement device or rather the columns.

Depend on the kind of Evaluation, different specific columns are needed and therefore it is neccessary to read all data (also with non values) at first.

my ugly approach:

```
import os
import numpy as np


FileName = 'testhash.txt'
f1 = open(FileName, 'r')
f2 = open(FileName[:-4] + '.tmp', 'w')
vrn = -9876543210 #very rare number
for line in f1:
        Newline = line.replace('##', str(vrn))
        Newline = Newline.replace('#i', str(vrn))
        f2.write(Newline)
f1.close()
f2.close()

Reduceddata = np.loadtxt(FileName[:-4] + '.tmp', skiprows=1, usecols=(1,3), delimiter=',')
os.remove(FileName[:-4] + '.tmp')

Enddata = Reduceddata[np.all(Reduceddata != vrn, axis=1),:].astype(int)


In [1]:Enddata
Out[1]: 
array([[5, 4],
       [9, 2],
       [2, 7]])
```

I Looking for a short and more elegant solution.

Comment: `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` work with anything that can feed it lines.  I often test with a list of strings, but a file reader and filter will work just as well.  So you don't need to write the converted lines back to a temporary file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution based on `converters` option in `np.loadtxt()`:

```
delimiter = ','
fillval = np.nan

with open('missingval.txt') as f:
    ncol = len(f.readline().split(delimiter))
converter = lambda s: fillval if s.strip()[0] == '#' else float(s)
converters = {i: converter for i in range(ncol)}

np.loadtxt('missingval.txt', delimiter=',', comments=None, 
           converters=converters, skiprows=1, encoding='ascii')
```

An even more concise solution would be based on `np.genfromtxt()`:

```
np.genfromtxt('missingval.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=np.int,  skip_header=1,
              filling_values=0, encoding='ascii', comments=None)
```

or, for floating point values,

```
np.genfromtxt('missingval.txt', delimiter=',', skip_header=1,
              filling_values=np.nan, encoding='ascii', comments=None)
```

#### Example:

Content of `'missingval.txt'`:

```
MD1,MD2,MD3,MD4,MD5
8,5,6,4,5
5,##,2,8,9
4,9,8,2,4
#i,2,9,7,2
```

Result of calling the above code:

```
In [97]: delimiter = ','
    ...: fillval = np.nan
    ...: 
    ...: with open('missingval.txt') as f:
    ...:     ncol = len(f.readline().split(delimiter))
    ...: converter = lambda s: fillval if s.strip()[0] == '#' else float(s)
    ...: converters = {i: converter for i in range(ncol)}
    ...: 
    ...: np.loadtxt('missingval.txt', skiprows=1, delimiter=',', comments=None,
    ...:            converters=converters, encoding='ascii')
Out[97]:
array([[ 8.,  5.,  6.,  4.,  5.],
       [ 5., nan,  2.,  8.,  9.],
       [ 4.,  9.,  8.,  2.,  4.],
       [nan,  2.,  9.,  7.,  2.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to AGN Gazer, that was very helpful.

Relating to my first Approach, my new code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

FileName = 'testhash.txt'

Alldata = np.genfromtxt(FileName, delimiter=',', skip_header=1,
          filling_values=np.nan, encoding='ascii', comments=None)

#### reducing array to the 1rd and 3rd column
Reduceddata = np.stack([Alldata[:,1],Alldata[:,3]], axis=1)

#### removing all rows with nan values
Enddata = Reduceddata[~np.any(np.isnan(Reduceddata), axis = 1)]


In[1]: Enddata
Out[1]: 
array([[5., 4.],
       [9., 2.],
       [2., 7.]])
```

I think, thats a short and elegant general solution.